# Bind dropdownlist which is inside gridview on 'OncheckedChange' event when checkbox of that row is checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="outdata">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-CssClass="profiledata" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" style="width: 50px !important;" onclick="CheckAll(this)" runat="server" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" OnCheckedChanged="chkSelect_CheckedChanged" runat="server" />
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnAssid" Value='<%# Eval("Asset_ID") %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="5px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Stop" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlGrdStops"></asp:DropDownList>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Suppose I have 2 columns in Gridview.
1. CheckBox
2. DropDownList

What Should be the code in the OnCheckedChange event of checkbox that whenever i check it the dropdownlist of the same row should be filled.

I tried RowDataBound event of gridview but the data is too large,so its take a long time in processing and it unnecessarily checks every rows checkbox.

Plase help since I am new.
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the NamingContainer of the CheckBox to locate the DropDownList in the same row. PS set `AutoPostBack` to true on the CheckBox.

```
protected void chkSelect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //cast the sender back to a checkbox
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;

    //get the current gridviewrow from the checkbox namingcontainer
    GridViewRow row = cb.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    //use findcontrol to locate the dropdownlist in that row
    DropDownList ddl = row.FindControl("ddlGrdStops") as DropDownList;

    //add the items to the dropdownlist
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "DropDownList found", Value = "1" });
}
```

Comment: IT worked just fine. I had to Add AutoPostback = true inside my checkbox. Thanks @VDWWD.